# In how many ways 5 boys and 3 girls can be seated such that no two girls are together?

Tags: permutations

In how many ways $5$ boys and $3$ girls can be seated such that no two girls are together?

Now I came up with a arrangement as

GBGBGBBB

Clearly, the boys can sit in $5!$ ways, but I am having a bit of trouble with girls as the third girl (prior to three B's) can also sit between last two boys and so this creates a confusion.
How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the $5$ boys stand in a line.  This can be done in $5!$ ways.  For the moment, add a boy at each end, who will be removed when we're done.  Now send the $3$ girls, one at a time, to stand between two boys.  The first girl has $6$ choices, the second girl will have $5$ choices, and the third girl will have $4$ choices.  This gives a total of

$$5!\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4=14{,}400$$

arrangements.  Remove the two extra boys, and have the others sit.

Remark:  the fiction of the extra two boys is simply to avoid having to elaborate that each girl can either wedge herself between two boys or else stand next to a boy at one end or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this Situation

$$\_ \mathbf B1 \_ \mathbf B2 \_ \mathbf B_3 \_ \mathbf B_4 \_ \mathbf B_5 \_ $$

The blank spaces are the places where 3 girls can be allotted. So in 6 spaces 3 girls can occupy in $6_{\mathbf P_3}$ ways and 5 boys will interchange between themselves in $5!$ ways.
So total number of ways is $5!×6_{\mathbf P_3}= 14400$